# Tkinterでウインドウを印刷するプログラムについて

Tags: python, python3, tkinter, 印刷

Raspberry Pi 3B+上でPython3のプログラムを書いています。
GUIにはTkinter を使っています。

さて、ウインドウ上のボタンを押すと、ウインドウ全体をプリンタで印刷するプログラムを書きたいと思います。
すでにCUPSをインストールし、他の標準アプリなどで印刷はできる状態になっています。

プログラムは以下ですが（一部省略）、ボタンを押すとエラーメッセージが出ます。
どうしたらいいでしょうか。

ソースコード

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*- coding: utf8 -*-
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import subprocess
from PIL import Image
import io

def printer():
    buf = io.StringIO()
    screen = (500, 500)
    bgcolor = (0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
    img = Image.new('RGB', screen, bgcolor)
    img.save(buf, 'PNG')
    p = subprocess.Popen('lp', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(buf.getvalue())
    p.stdin.close()
    buf.close()

root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes('-type','splash')
root.geometry("800x480")
button = tk.Button(root,text="閉じる",command=sys.exit)
button.pack()
button2 = tk.Button(root,text="印刷",command=printer)
button2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

エラーメッセージ

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/tkinter/__init__.py", Line 1705, in __call__
　　return　self.func(*args)
File　"/home/pi/Projects/tk.py", line　19, in　printer
　　　img.save(buf, 'PNG’)
　Fi!e　"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line　1994, in　save　　　　　　　　　　　　
　　　save_handler(self, fp, filename)
　File　"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py"，line　773, in _save
　　　fp.write(_MAGIC)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=265429&p=1613438

Comment: `_MAGIC` は byte 型のインスタンスなのですが、`buf = io.StringIO()` としているためにエラーが発生しています。

Comment: @metropolis コメント欄は回答欄ではないです。